# iTunes for Windows finds less files to import than iTunes for Mac

Tags: itunes

On a Windows removable disk, I have a folder called audio jukebox. Under that folder I have a folder for each artist and under each of these folders there are one or more folders each representing an album and in each of these folders are the songs in that album. Windows reports that I have 1,445 folder and 10,498 files.

When I delete all songs in iTunes and then import them into my PC, iTunes says I have 7,064 items. Then I do the same thing on my MacBook and iTunes says I have 7,114 items.

Why are they not the same on both computers?

Comment: If you export each one as a playlist, then use a text-comparison program, what are the differences? I would guess there is some particular file type that Windows doesn't like for some reason, and/or the path is too long for Windows to work with.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen with many other things on mac, such as your storage breakdown. The simple fix is to restart your mac and open iTunes back up again. Sometimes, macs need to "catch up".

Sources:

- Apple store worker

Comment: Not sure I buy the underlying explanation, but even if that were to be accepted, that would only explain things if Mac iTunes was showing _less_ files than Windows iTunes, not more as it actually is.

Comment: I am not sure than, it may be something different. Since you did not provide that much information, that was the answer I could come up with.

Comment: I didn't post the question. :P

Comment: @tubedogg I know, I did that so the OP could see it. (Not really directed at you)